# Displaying User Agreement in SFDC Customer Portal

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

We use SFDC Customer Portal for allowing our customers access to portal features such as product documentation and case management. One of our business requirements is to require customers to accept an agreement before they can choose a password and gain access to the portal.

Is this scenario possible with configuration of the customer portal or is this something that will require us to code custom visual force pages? Appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Thanks

-Subhash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I have researched on stack overflow and on google too.. But I have not came across such workflow. If anyone has already implemented suce kind of workflow it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration setting in Customer Portal that lets you do this natively. However you can easily implement this using a Visualforce page. Customize the landing page (login page) so that the login options are only shown when the user accepts the User Agreement using javascript or visualforce ajax.

Anup

Comment: How can i configure landing page in Customer portal? In Customer Portal we configure landing tab, but can we set landing page?

Comment: By landing page, I meant the login page. You can configure the login page, right? This [article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites) might give you some clues.

Comment: I was referring Landing page as the page after login. When Customer Portal user logs in, I want to take him to Welcome Page(VF Page without tab). From their on "Skip" button click he will be taken to "home.jsp". I want to implement this workflow. I am not able to set this "Welcome" page as first page after login(landing page).